# Possible to perform a bitwise operation on a 1000 bit number in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, binary, bit-manipulation

Spawned by this question:

[Bitwise AND in Sql Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396368/bitwise-and-in-sql-server/5396525#5396525)

In response to the above question I suggested converting a varchar(1000)  that contained a binary number to it's integer equivalent and performing bitwise operations on it.  While this would be ok for much smaller binary numbers, it is too large to work with any method I am aware of.

Does anyone know of a way to do this in SQL Server?  Is it possible to apply bitwise operations to the binary datatype?

Comment: As per this link from microsoft, binary can only be one operand left or right, but not the both. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176122.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answered in the other question.  As for this one

You can not use the built in SQL Server functions, bitwise AND `&` does not even work on varbinary.  So you need to chunk it into blocks and cast to int/bigint, then perform bit operations on them.

I have answered this before, but I cannot find it and am too lazy to rewrite - here's an implementation I found on the net.  http://www.dmertl.com/files/posts/binary_bitwise.sql

Comment: I apparently deleted that file at some point, it's back now. You can also check out the [blog post](http://www.dmertl.com/blog/?p=6) for more info.